# print max with pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void MaxandMin(int * arr, int len,int **p1, int **p2);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[5] = {1,3,5,2,4};
    int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    int * maxPtr;
    int * minPtr;
    int ** dptr1 = &minPtr;
    int ** dptr2 = &maxPtr;

    MaxandMin(arr,len, dptr1, dptr2);

    printf("max is %d, min is %d\n", *maxPtr, *minPtr);

    return 0;   
}

void MaxandMin(int * arr, int len, int **p1, int **p2)
{
    int * max;
    int * min;
    max = min = &arr[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; len++)                     
    {
        if (*max < *(arr + i))
            max = (arr + i);
        if (*min > *(arr + i))
            min = (arr + i);
    }

    *p1 = max;
    *p2 = min;
}
```

I want to print max and min number in the array arr. I think there's nothing wrong, but I can't see any output. I have tried some more expression of pointer and addresses. So may I ask how I can see output of this program in this situation? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increment `i` and not `len`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{ ... }

*p1 = min;
*p2 = max;
```

(Also, the assignments to `*p1` and `*p2`, are mixed up).

A few other tips

- You can just write `max = min = arr`.
- You don't need `dptr1` and `dptr2`: `MaxandMin(arr,len, &minPtr, &maxPtr)`

Comment: The logic for `min` and `max` was correct in the original question. If the current value of `max` is **smaller** than the array value, update `max`